# Socket.IO with Express.JS routing

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

Creating my small chat wasn't too hard, but now I am trying to create real-time comments system. My current configuration uses latest Node, Express and Socket.IO and I have no idea how to create separate comment page. How to connect Express' routing and SocketIO when routes are defined before I can open socket connection?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var swig = require('swig');

app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view cache', false);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('chat');
});

var server = app.listen(80);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('open', messages);

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: [lmgtfy](http://expressjs.com/guide.html)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  More of a description of the desired result and what part of that you are stuck on would help.  There are lots of examples in the express documentation for how to create a new route for a new page.  What part of that is not working for you?